Why did the ice form?
I freeze chicken breasts in plastic baggies and thaw them when I am ready to use them.  I will thaw them by putting them in this metal bowl, filled it over halfway up with room temperature tap water, then I just place the bag in the bowl.  I then put the bowl in the refrigerator.  A few hours later, I have a defrosted, yet still cold, chicken breast sitting in bowl of cold water.  Ive done this countless times with the exact same result.
However this time, I had opened my fridge a few hours later and was genuinely surprised.  I got a different result.  The chicken in the plastic bag was defrosted, but the bowl was filled - well not filled - but had a significant amount of ice on the surface and on the bottom.  You cant tell from the pictures, but its not a thin sheet, but over a centimeter thick.
The fridge is kept at 38 degrees F (3.33 C).  The contents havent changed, except these specific contents were added.  Maybe a Dr. Pepper or two was removed...
I dont understand what happened and why the ice formed.  The heat energy from the water went into the chicken, which caused it to unfreeze.  However, that should not have caused the water to freeze.  Heat energy from the metal bowl and air should go into the water to keep it from freezing.  Regardless the water (I assume) had more mass than the chicken...
I am wracking my brain here trying to figure out what happened and why?



Remember that this is not a system in thermodynamic equilibrium. So I assume the chicken was still near below freezing temp, even if it might look perfectly soft, and the heat transfer from the water to the chicken was fast enough so that part of the water closer to the chicken dropped below water freezing temp. It is a transitory step, it will end up with liquid water and the chicken at the fridge temp.

Its doesnt look defrosted.  I removed it from the bag and it is completely defrosted.

yes, but at what temperature was it?

To produce a time averaged temperature of 3C inside the fridge means that the actual temperature will cycle back and forth between something like -5C and +8C as the compressor unit turns itself on and off. I'll bet your fridge has a forced-air heat exchanger in which the chilled air enters the fridge through a diffuser vent that has a fan behind it. If you put the bowl of chicken & water under the diffuser vent then the sub-freezing air has a chance to take the surface temperature of the bowl below freezing which will be a fast process because the heat transfer is forced. The heat transfer between the chicken and the water is not forced because there is no pump moving the water around and so the water in the interior of the bowl can be slightly above the freezing point while the surface is in the process of freezing.
Now note that in the phase diagram for water, the water undergoes a significant increase in density as it cools down but just before & during solidification it expands enough to shatter iron pipes in the plumbing in your house in cold weather.
The almost-almost-almost frozen water may then segregate via buoyancy to the top of the bowl and solidify there first before the bottom-most water can freeze.

It's not clear why this time it was different, so this is more a hypothesis than a definite conclusion. We would need to know a lot more about the details of the set-up than even you probably know. But I can suggest a mechanism for how it could have happened.
The freezer keeps things at about -20 C, so it is, relatively speaking, very cold. When the chicken is first put in the water, the water around the sides cools, and because cold water is less dense, convects. I think that because it was moving, it supercooled to below 0 C without freezing. Only when it stops (which it does at the boundaries of the water, on the surface and down the sides of the bowl) does it actually freeze. The water underneath the chicken is trapped there, and cannot convect, so you get a thin layer of ice that insulates it from the water. Heat enters the chicken mainly around the sides, where convection speeds up heat transfer enormously, the cold water rises to the top, and there is a pool of warm water below it at the bottom. As heat transfer progresses and the chicken approaches zero, the layer of cold water at the top of the bowl expands downwards and the layer of warmer water at the bottom shrinks. The water right at the bottom will probably be at 4 C, where water is most dense. Eventually, the suface of the chicken rises above zero and the supercooling and subsequent freezing stop, but it takes time for the heat to penetrate the ice that has been formed just as it takes time to penetrate the chicken. The convecting pool of warm-ish water at 4 C at the bottom up to 0 C at the top surrounds the chicken to the end, which is why it defrosts. Heat from the water, and the surroundings, will also be melting the ice, but heat conducts through solid ice very slowly compared to convection.
Heat transfer in cold water is complicated - largely because it is a liquid, and so convects, and also because water has the peculiar property of being most dense at a temperature above its freezing point. You can get all sorts of odd effects - like the Mpemba effect, where hot water often freezes faster than cold water. A bowl of water does not act as a simple thermodynamic 'block', entirely characterised by a single average temperature. The spatial distribution of temperature is critical for understanding how convection will affect the rate of heat flow.
I can't say why it happened only on this occasion. The initial temperature and amount of water you put in the bowl, or how 'stirred up' it was are obvious candidates. How clean the bowl was could have an effect, in terms of its ability to nucleate ice formation. The temperature in both fridge and freezer cycles up and down, as the thermostat kicks in. Contaminants (e.g. oil on the outside of the bag) can affect the freezing point of water. There are many factors to consider.
